# Pegar o valor do input radio com javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um quiz de perguntas e gostaria de pegar o valor do input radio, que são as opções de resposta. Alguma dica de como posso fazer isso usando javascript apenas?

```html
<form>
 <h3>1. Which tag should used to represent the "header" of a document?</h3>
 <ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a">head</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b">header</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c">heading</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="d">main</li>
 </ul>  
 <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o método javascript [queryselector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) e combinar os seletores javascript:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score 4):

Para capturar os `input's` do `form` usando apenas *javascript*:

```
<form id="form">
    <h3>1. Which tag should used to represent the "header" of a document?</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a">head</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b">header</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c">heading</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="d">main</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="btn-salvar" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');
    var botao = document.querySelector('#btn-salvar');

    botao.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(form.q1.value);
    });
</script>
```

Obs.: O `event.preventDefault()` tem por comportamento evitar o carregamento normal da página que contém um `form` com botão do tipo `submit`. Se não deseja que isso aconteça, deve-se chamar o `event` dentro de sua função anônima, para evitar que o form recarregue a página.

Comment: Deu certo aqui! Valeu! Só poderia me explicar essa função `event.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: atualizei a resposta com a observação do significado do `event.preventDefault()`.